# Position a listview control when Datagrid cell text change in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid control with 5 columns namely Item Code,Item Name, Qty,Rate,Amount respectively. I want to populate Items on a listview control when I type something on the cell on Item Name column in the Datagrid. The listview must be appear below of the cell which I typing.I dont know how to get the Postion the listview when the cell textchange .Help me to get rid of these .

My Window is look like :

```
 <Grid  Width="900" Height="567" Background="{StaticResource Background}">
      <my:DataGrid Name="dgvSales" BeginningEdit="dgvSales_BeginningEdit" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="13,150,9,117" KeyDown="dgvSales_KeyDown" MouseDown="dgvSales_MouseDown" PreparingCellForEdit="dgvSales_PreparingCellForEdit" MouseRightButtonUp="dgvSales_MouseRightButtonUp">
                    <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <my:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="naam" Header="Code" Width="120" Binding="{Binding ProductCode}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Name" Width="200" Binding="{Binding ProductName}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <my:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Unit" Width="100"></my:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Purchase Rate" Width="100" Binding="{Binding PurchaseRate}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Qty}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Amount}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                    </my:DataGrid.Columns>
                </my:DataGrid>

<ListView Height="161" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="461,0,51,257" Name="lstvwProductCode" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="388">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Record_Id}" Header="Record ID" Width="0" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Product_Code}" Header="Pcode" Width="110" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Product_Name}" Header="Product" Width="180" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the poition of your ListViewItem like so:

```
FrameworkElement item = (FrameworkElement)DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data);
Point position = item.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, item.ActualHeight), Window.GetWindow(DataGrid));
```

Now you can change the position of your ListView:

```
ListView.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(position.X, position.Y);
```

EDIT:
You can also use the EventArgs of you BeginningEdit-Event:

```
    private void DataGrid_OnBeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Point newPosition = new Point();
        if (!(lstvwProductCode.RenderTransform is TransformGroup))
            lstvwProductCode.RenderTransform = new TransformGroup();// set the ListView's RenderTransform to a TransformGroup if it isn't already

        DataGrid dg = GetRowsDataGrid(e.Row); //get the Row's corresponding DataGrid with the help of the VisualTreeHelper. You cant use the Column here, because it won't get added to the visual tree.
        if (dg != null)
        {
            double rowX = GetColumnXPosition(e.Column, dg); //get the x position. Here you can't use .TranslatePoint because - again - it doesn't belong to the visual tree, so you have to sum up all columns width' to the column where the changes are made.
            newPosition = e.Row.TranslatePoint(new Point(rowX + 5, e.Row.ActualHeight), this); //translate this point to a point on your main window.
        }

        if (newPosition != new Point())
        {
            Point tPoint = lstvwProductCode.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), this);//add this point
            ((TransformGroup) lstvwProductCode.RenderTransform).Children.Add(
                new TranslateTransform(newPosition.X - tPoint.X, newPosition.Y - tPoint.Y));
        }
    }

    private double GetColumnXPosition(DataGridColumn column, DataGrid grid)
    {
        double result = 0.0;

        if (grid == null)
            return result;

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridColumn dgc = grid.Columns[i];
            if (dgc.Equals(column))
                break;

            result += dgc.ActualWidth;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private DataGrid GetRowsDataGrid(DataGridRow row)
    {
        DependencyObject result = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(row);
        while (result != null && !(result is DataGrid))
        {
            result = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(result);
        }
        return result as DataGrid;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Florian Gl , I dont understand what data and lvi means will u clarify me this..    FrameworkElement item = (FrameworkElement)DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data);
Point position = lvi.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, item.ActualHeight), Window.GetWindow(DataGrid));

Comment: Sry, lvi was a copy and paste mistake, I changed it. `data` is the DataContext of the DataGridItem you want to get. E.g. if your DataGrid is bound to a List of objects, data is one item of this list.

Comment: Hi Florian Gl, I binded my Datagrid item source as  to observable collection

Comment: Ok, so `FrameworkElement item = (FrameworkElement)DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(YourObservableCollection[0]);` would give you the first Item of your DataGrid.

Comment: sir , ok i did as you said . Now my listview is shown but it is postioned at the below of my current form(Usercontrol) but actually i want to postion the listiview on the cell which I enter ProductName ,I appreciate your help sir

Comment: sir,what this means item.ActualHeight and  Window.GetWindow(DataGrid) Here DataGrid means my Datagrid control or My parent window which contain all these things ?

Comment: DataGrid means your DataGrid (`dgvSales`). I found another solution, have a look at my edit.

Comment: sir , Still have the problem , the listview is shown as very below level.Actually my datagrid all other controls are on a usercontrol namely PurchaseOrder.I have a Main window ( wpf window control) from which all the child usercontrols are shown ,is the reason why the listview is shown on below ?

Comment: Wola !! nice work sir , thats working when we click a cell using mouse ,the listview will be positioned on the point where we clicked on the cell.But sir what we do if the user is edit the cell via keyboard not using mouse ?

Comment: Edited my post, next try^^

Comment: got it ,its working perfect sir , now How do I determine which column the user is clicked in codebehind(datagrid_BeginningEdit). If the user clicked  in Product column then I want to list products from the database into the product listview and  map the selected Product back to the datagrid's Product column how to do this sir ?

Comment: The DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs hold information about the current Column and Row (`e.Column` and `e.Row`).

Comment: sir ,I replaced my default product column to a template column with a textbox in it.Now I want to postion the listview on the textbox when the textbox_PreviewKeydown event fire how to do this I dont get here e.row and e.column how to do this sir

Comment: Doesnt the DataGridBeginningEdit-event get fired when editting the textbox?

Comment: sir please see the image link the listview is postioned slightly right side if I use template column  :[IMG]http://i40.tinypic.com/2iavq80.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: but  Florian Gl ,I want to show the listview only when the cell keydown

Comment: To your first issue: `newPosition = e.Row.TranslatePoint(new Point(rowX + 5, e.Row.ActualHeight), this);` change the 5 to a lower value to position your listview a bit more left. If you want to position your listview only on keydown, add a condition like `if (e.EditingEventArgs is KeyboardEventArgs)` to your `DataGrid_OnBeginningEdit`-method.

Comment: I would say the rest is up to you, I won't tell you how to write your whole programm.^^

Comment: @ Florian Gl  very helpful it save me great burden